# Android ML Kit Translator.getClient() Unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, google-mlkit

I am following [this explanation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/translation/android#translate-text) and having a problem with this code:

```
val options = TranslatorOptions.Builder()
    .setSourceLanguage(TranslateLanguage.ENGLISH) 
    .setTargetLanguage(TranslateLanguage.GERMAN) .build() 
val englishGermanTranslator = Translator.getClient(options)
```

Only `getClient()` remained in red. Everything else was properly imported with *Alt+Enter*.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an error/typo in the documentation. `Translator` should be changed to `Translation`:

```
val englishGermanTranslator = Translation.getClient(options)
```

*You might want to [create an issue](https://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=https%3A%2F%2Fissuetracker.google.com%2Fissues%2Fnew%3Fcomponent%3D897785%26template%3D1457144)*.

Comment: The [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173209142) has been created.

Comment: This has now been fixed in the documentation. Thanks!